# jQuery Mobile: data-transition is not triggered?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to use `data-transition` in my jquery mobile project. the issue that I am having is very strange as it works on some `<a></a>` but it doesn't work on others!

to explain this, if i have a link like this:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-ajax="false">
        <li data-icon='false'><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><a data-fajax="false" href="contact.html" data-transition="flip">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

it works perfectly fine and `data-transition="flip"` trigeres just fine.

But if i have the links as sub-menus like so:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-ajax="false">

<li data-icon='false' class="menu-item-has-children"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><a href="" data-transition="flip">My Account</a>

<ul data-role="listview" class="sub-menu">

<li data-icon='false'><i class="fa fa-heart"></i><a data-fajax="false" href="Copy of products.html" data-transition="flip">Wish List<span class="menu-mark">0</span></a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

could someone please advise on this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What's with that data-fajax="false"? There's no such attribute in JQuery Mobile documentation. Have you tried removing that to see if data-transition works?